# Wordpress URL shorter Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I actually Building my new blog and stopped on one of the last open issues. I want to short my external links in each blog post. I upload my blogpost primarly per mail so i need an Option to short the external link automaticly or per html shortcode. I checked the wordpress plugin site to find a plugin that can realize that:

I checked following plugins:

- Pretty Link lite
- Affiliate Link
- goo.gl
- Google Shortlink by BestWebSoft (give an unknown error)
- shorty lite

Any tips?

Regards 
Timo

Comment: Please note that questions asking for opinions or recommendations are discouraged: Please see See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

So i checked the last 48 Hours to find so Kind of plugin. It Looks like that no plugin can do that what i descriped. I checked the Google shorten API and short the links before i send them with the email Service to the wordpress blog.

Thanks

regards 
Timo